# Integration of a $k$-form over chains

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

In Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, he defines the integral of a $k$-form over a $k$-chain, and proves a version of Stokes' theorem for this situation, before moving on to discuss the integral of a differential form over a manifold.  Other books, such as *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by Lee and *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, seem to skip this step.  They define the integral of a $k$-form over a $k$-manifold without mentioning or proving theorems about $k$-chains.  (Am I correct about that?)

What is the advantage (if any) of Spivak's approach?  To me, $k$-chains appear to be an unnecessary weird definition in a subject that already has too many unfamiliar definitions.

Comment: Most likely, for the same reason I explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667317/why-integrate-on-cubes-thats-not-injective/3681164#3681164).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for that explanation, that was enlightening.

Answer (score 3):

In Lee the integral is only defined for an n-form on an n-manifold. If you want to integrate a lower dimensional k-form (k < n), you need to use a submanifold of dimension k and pull the form back with inclusion. I believe one purpose of chains is to avoid talking about submanifolds and orientations of manifold boundaries. Instead We can integrate lower dimensional forms in a higher dimensional space using singular chains.